# Which canon was Star Tours in before Star Wars Legends?

Tags: star-wars, disney

Prior to Legends becoming all non-canon, the Holocron described [G-canon, T-canon, C-canon, S-canon, and N-canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69345/what-are-the-different-star-wars-canons).

- Which of these did the 1987-2010 version of [Star Tours](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Tours_(real-world)) fall in?
- Which of these did the 2011 [Star Tours: The Adventures Continue](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76559/how-does-the-new-star-tours-even-remotely-fit-into-the-star-wars-canon/76561#76561) versions fall in?
- Which of these did the Orlando, Tokyo, and Paris versions fall in?

Comment: My understanding is that they were always totally non-canon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually unclear, but signs point to them both being non-canon (N-canon)

**The Original Star Tours Ride**

[Wookieepedia discusses the issues here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Tours_%28real-world%29), but the tl;dr of it is that the Death Star we see in the ride does not accurately match either of the Death Stars in the movies. Additionally, the attack run we see also does not accurately match - though the destruction of the Death Star is somewhat close to Luke's trench run against the original Death Star.

The mis-matched details in the ride lead some riders to believe that the Death Star on the ride is either a third Death Star, or an early prototype.

The existence of the company "Star Tours" did make into T-Canon with a brief mention in the *Clone Wars* episode [Lightsaber Lost](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber_Lost), and things like the existence of the speeder model and the pilot droid model made it into C-Canon with appearances in [Specter of the Past](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Specter_of_the_Past) and [The New Essential Guide to Droids](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_New_Essential_Guide_to_Droids).

As far as I can tell, all of the various Star Tours ride locations used the same video, so they would have all been the same (non-)canon level.

**Star Tours: The Legends Continue**

There was no way to rectify this one into any sort of canon, as [discussed here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/76559/5184). We see characters and events from across a 50 year span of in-universe time, with characters who cannot canonically exist at those locations. It can only have been described as N-Canon.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is that they were considered "N-canon" (non-canon).

The events depicted; notably the presence of the starliner at the destruction of the Death Star,  the fact that R2-D2 was on board the starliner when he should have been on board Luke's X-Wing,  etc etc would seem to heavily conflict with the accepted canon seen in the films.

On top of that, due to the innovative multi - ending format, the rides would actually conflict **with themselves**, taking the riders on one of up to 52 different journeys.